# I Installed TensorFlow-gpu using anaconda and it cant find a file "cudart64_10.dll", but that file exists

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

Like I said before, after installing TensorFlow-gpu by anaconda im getting this error in python terminal

W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found

The thing is, that this file actually exists in this dir (maybe this will help) C:\Users\MyUser\Anaconda3\envs\Gpu_Tensor_Flow\Library\bin
Please help me, because I have no idea what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue
Jozef Jarosciak published an answer that worked for me, visit https://www.joe0.com/2019/10/19/how-resolve-tensorflow-2-0-error-could-not-load-dynamic-library-cudart64_100-dll-dlerror-cudart64_100-dll-not-found/

I downloaded the cudart64_100.dll directly from his website and put it in this path (using windows, i guess it is the same for you since install on linux is pretty easy) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin\

It is weird because I installed all software requirements with lastest version, still tensorflow seems to load this old dll, may be tensorflow is not up to date yet.